# Get date in Leap years php

Tags: php, date

I want to convert 59 to 2012-feb-29. I already know current year is 2012. I try following code. but it give 2012-mar-01.

```
$string = '59 2012';
$date1 = date_create_from_format('z Y', $string);
$date_time = date_format($date1, 'Y-m-d');
echo $date_time;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`strtotime()`](http://www.php.net/strtotime) instead:

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('2012-01 +59 day'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime(date('Y-01-01')) + 59 * 86400);
```

***Update:***

The problem in your code is because `z` is starting from `0`, so you need to minus `1`.

```
$date1 = date_create_from_format('z', 59 - 1);
$date_time = date_format($date1, 'Y-m-d');
echo $date_time;
```

Comment: Funny, if it was any other day OP would have probably spotted the off-by-one :)

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this issue before and this is the solution I came up to:

```
/**
 * Get date if leap year
 * 
 * @param int $year z date format
 * @param int $date Y date format
 * 
 * @return object|null
 */
private function getLeapYearDate($year, $date)
{
    if ($date >= 1 && $date <= 59) {
        return date_create_from_format('z', $date - 1);
    } else if ($date == 60) {
        return date_create($year . '-02-29');
    } else if ($date >= 61 && $date <= 365) {
        return date_create_from_format('z', $date - 2);
    } else if ($date == 366) {
        return date_create($year . '-12-31');
    }

    return null;
}
```

Hope this helps! Have a good day...